# bagaimana cara menginstall steghide lewat mac

Tags: character-encoding

saya ingin melakukan command steghide untuk keperluan program saya, akan tetapi command tersebut tidak dapat di temukan.

Oleh karena itu saya di beri petunjuk untuk menginstall steghide

saat saya mencoba melakukan brew install steghide

ternyata tidak bisa, apa yang bisa saya lakukan untuk menangani hal tersebut ?

Comment: Tolong gunakan bahasa inggris